# c# how can i click button in webbrowser ducument if the element has on ID?

Tags: c#, web-applications, web, browser, element

i have a c# web browser and when it loads the page i want the program to click on Element

i found he way to click this element when i know the ID

```
   htmlelement    ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("the ID"); if (ele != null)
                ele.InvokeMember("click");
```

but some elements have no ID or changeable ID  how can i do this by value or class or something else  instead of ID  ??

the web page is java page maybe a got the the source code but what is the right way to do that

and if i know how to identify the element how could i change the value if the element is a textbox ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
var elems = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("document.querySelectorAll('some-css-selector')");
```

might work.

Comment: plz can you explane :  ('some-css-selector') how i get it

Comment: 'some-css-selector' is a placeholder for a CSS selector you can use to identify your element. I can't tell which selector to use because I don't know how your page looks.

Comment: yes you r right  CSS in webdevloper 

i want to try can you give me CSS for facebook login button for examle ?
i maybe noisy for you   sory but no one can i ask for

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a web automation tool like http://watin.org/ It will do everything you want and more.

Have a look here from more information: [Website Automation Using C# and WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378449/website-automation-using-c-sharp-and-webbrowser)